# extract a specific tag from xml file using beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an xml file (lets call is abc.xml) which looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<properties>
  <product name="XYZ" version="123"/>
  <application-links>
    <application-links>
      <id>111111111111111</id>
      <name>Link_1</name>
      <primary>true</primary>
      <type>applinks.ABC</type>
      <display-url>http://ABC.displayURL</display-url>
      <rpc-url>http://ABC.displayURL</rpc-url>
    </application-links>
  </application-links>
</properties>
```

my python code is like this

```
f = open ('file.xml', 'r')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(f,'lxml')

print(soup.product)

for applinks in soup.application-links:
    print(applinks)
```

which prints the following

```
<product name="XYZ" version="123"></product>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 7, in <module>
    for applinks in soup.application-links:
NameError: name 'links' is not defined
```

Please can you help me understand how to print lines which have tags including a dash/hyphen '-'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if `beautifulsoup` is the best option here, but I really suggest using the `ElementTree` module in python like so:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.parse('file.xml').getroot()
>>> for app in root.findall('*/application-links/'):
...     print(app.text)
111111111111111
Link_1
true
applinks.ABC
http://ABC.displayURL
http://ABC.displayURL
```

So, to print the value inside the `<name>` tag, you can do so:

```
>>> for app in root.findall('*/application-links/name'):
...     print(app.text)
Link_1
```

Comment: let me give this a try and will let you know how I go.

Comment: have never really used ElementTree before so need to read up, found this tutorial https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-xml-elementtree, will read through and come back to your code here. For the time being, I am trying to print out the name attribute from the application-links/application-links

Comment: It's ok... I've edited my answer to print just the `name`